# How to get members of customize ListView in RAD Studio

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder

How to use TListView's DynamicApperance's Item members by C++ code in RAD Studio 10.2?
I took one ListView. I have change the itemAppearance to **DynamicAppearance**.
Now I want to populate the list by C++ code. There are **Text** & **Text1** items inside in listview. So to assigning the text I wrote below code.

```
TListViewItem* item = ListView->Items->Add();
item->Text = "MyText";  //item->Text1 = "Text1"; (Gives error).
```

Above code works for item->Text. But when I said **item->Text1**, RAD stdio gives me error that, Text1 is not a member of ListViewItem.
So how do I get the Members of Customized ListView?

Thanks in Advance.

**Image1**
[image]

**Image2**
[image]

**Image3**
[image]

Comment: You should add that you're talking about FMX and not VCL. Also property Text1 does not exists, it obviously gives you an error.

Comment: I removed the erroneous tags. Tags are important. Take the time to use the right ones. Now, there is no Text1 property. You'll need to explain what you think it is.

Comment: I have added the snaps. I have take TListView. I changed the appearance of list item from ListImage to DynamicAppearance. By doing this Text1 item get added in structure of ListView. I want to access this Text1 by code, which is not showing by the Intellisense of RAD studio. For this i am getting the error for Text1.

Answer (score 1):

```
TListViewItem* item = ListView->Items->Add();
item->Text = "item 1";
TListViewItem* item = ListView->Items->Add();
item->Text = "item 2";

TListViewItem* item = ListView->Items->Item[0];
item.Text = item.Text + " +";
TListViewItem* item = ListView->Items->Item[1];
item.Text = item.Text + " +";
```

Comment: Thanks for a comment.
I just don't know what's to explain, just posted a sample how to access
items in TListView.

Comment: I have take TListView. I changed the appearance of list item from ListImage to DynamicAppearance. By doing this Text1 item get added in  structure of ListView. I want to access this Text1 by code, which is not showing by the Intellisense of RAD studio. For this i am getting the error for Text1.

Comment: I have added the snaps as well in my question.

Comment: Have a look:

  TListViewItem* Li = ListView1->Items->Add();
  TListItemText* Txt = Li->Objects->FindObject('Text1');
  Txt->Text = 'AAA';

Comment: TListItemText* Txt = Li->Objects->FindObject('Text1');  this statement gives me compilation error.

Comment: @Sarthak mirajkar, oh I'm sorry. It's necessary to cast types:
TListItemText* Txt = (TListItemText*)Li->Objects->FindObject('Text1');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169740/discussion-between-alex-kalabukhov-and-sarthak-mirajkar).

Answer (score 0):

Try following codes for custom appearance.. I hope it helps.

```
TListViewItem* item;
ListView1->Items->Clear();

ListView1->BeginUpdate();
while(!myQuery->Eof)
{
   item             = ListView1->Items->Add();

   item->Text       = myQuery->FieldByName("Description1")->AsString;
   item->Detail     = myQuery->FieldByName("Size")        ->AsString;
   item->ButtonText = myQuery->FieldByName("Note")        ->AsString;
   item->Tag        = myQuery->FieldByName("ProductID")   ->AsInteger;
   item->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("C:\\TEST.JPG");
   myQuery->Next();
}
ListView1->EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

This is code bro!

```
item: TListViewItem;
begin
  item := lvList.Items.Add;
  (item as TAppearanceListViewItem).Data['name'] := AName;
```